# Why does the speed of sun play a role in dark matter detection

Tags: dark-matter, sun, particle-detectors

I'm reading the book supersymmetry and beyond from Gordon Kane and got a bit confused at the point where he started explaining how we can check whether the signal we got at a detector is truly because we detected cold dark matter or e.g. a nucleus decayed.

"For example, during one half of the year, the earth and the sun move in the same direction so their speeds add, giving a larger velocity and therefore more frequent interactions. During the other half they move oppositely, so the speeds substract, giving less frequent interactions; thus the event rate should vary in a predicted way over the course of the year." /Supersymmetry and Beyond, revised edition, Gordon Kane, Basic Books 2013

My question would be: When does the earth and the sun eve move in different directions? I mean the picture I have in mind when I think about eath-sun movement is this one: https://pin.it/si7f2dxzmiugkf

Comment: Note that the animation you linked is an artist's conception and is not accurate to the real world. Earth's orbit around the sun and the sun's orbit around the galaxy are at a moderate relative tilt, not a full 90 degrees as the animation depicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the orbit of the sun around the galactic center; for half the year, the Earth's orbit and the sun's orbits move in the same direction, relative to the galactic center.  For the other half, the Earth is moving against the sun's orbit relative to the galactic center.

Comment: True.  Of course, this only works if the dark matter is not rotating around the galactic center along with everything else.  Has that been demonstrated yet?

Comment: No, it has not.  The existence of dark matter hasn't been demonstrated yet, which I suspect is the purpose of this experiment; depending on the results, it could either demonstrate non-rotating dark matter, or be mildly inconclusive.